# Regexp for sequence of characters

Tags: regex

I am having trouble to find a regexp that accepts only the following sequence of characters :

> D, D0, D00, D00D, D00D0, D00D00, D00D00D, D00P, D00P0, D00P00,
>   D00P00R, D00P00R0, D00P00R00 etc...

Here is what I did

```
^D$|^D0$|^D00([DPR]0{0,2})*$
```

but this also accepts strings like

> D00DD, D00DDD, D00PPP

Comment: Why `[DPR]` presents in your regex? Is it allowed too? Please, clarify sequence creation principle.

Comment: Language or tool you are using, and you can you explain the pattern you are tring to match a bit more because it is not pretty obvious ?

Comment: Are `D00P00D00` or `D00P00P00` valid or not?

Comment: Yes they are valid also.  Each time it is a combination of 1 letter D,P R followed by 0, 1 or 2 digits only.  So D00P is valid, D00P0 is valid, D00P00 is valid, D00P00P00 is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should match what you are looking for:

```
^D(00[DPR])*0{0,2}$
```

Comment: You was quicker than me, here is the [Regexr for this expression](http://regexr.com?3699f)

Answer (score 1):

Only the last zeroes should be 0 to 2, all the others should be exactly 2.

This regex should do it:

```
^D(00D)*0{0,2}$
```

The check for `D` and `D0` are not needed with the above.

[Test](http://www.rubular.com/r/CCO6xQs4Ri).

Answer (score 0):

`/d(?=0{0,2})+0{0,2}+/` for javascript, you should never need `^D$|^D0$|^D00`

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
^D0{0,2}$|^(D0{1,2})+D?$
```